# Bugs/Error, any specific way/format to submit these

Tags: support, documentation, error-message, bug-reporting-process

Recently I have been getting many errors particularly in `documentation`, though I asked question here on the one of the error, but I don't think there's any appropriate answer for the same, since it's a bug.

Is there any specific way to submit bugs, or I had to just keep on asking questions for each specific error I get?

Answer (score 2):

Some errors are automatically logged and reported. I'm not sure if this is the case for Documentation or not. But Meta is indeed the place to file bug reports, using the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag. There are lots of them here already. When posting, follow the standard format for bug reports:

- state the bug/problem clearly (screen shots are helpful; free-hand red circles are appreciated)
- describe what you were doing when the bug occurred
- include any important details about your environment (browser name and version, operating system, the fact that you're located on an island in the middle of the South Pacific and using a smoke-signal-based TCP/IP protocol, etc.)
- provide the necessary steps (in sufficient detail) to reproduce the bug (if you can reproduce it)
- optionally, comment on its severity (how is it affecting your ability to use the site?)

Anyone can post an answer to such questions, including to disagree ("this is not a bug"), to provide additional information ("I can reproduce this bug under the following circumstances"), to raise its priority ("this is an extremely serious bug, it is blocking me from interacting productively with the site"), and to suggest a fix (this is most common for HTML/CSS bugs, where most of the information needed to debug the issue is publicly available).

Actually *getting* a resolution and an answer to that effect does indeed require a Stack Exchange team member. They do monitor Meta, though, and definitely pay attention to the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag. You'll see them occasionally retagging questions that have been erroneously tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). :-)

That said, I agree that the sound of crickets chirping for many Documentation-related bug reports is rather deafening.

Comment: Please do search for an existing bug first; as Cody Gray notes, there are lots of them already.